# How to transform a list of strings to a list I can plot with ListLinePlot?

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics

I have to plot a list of data given by my professor. Here you can see the data is in txt. format and the problem is I can't plot it because the list is in string. Also, when I use the ListLinePlot function the out is "...is not a list of number or pairs of numbers."[image]

Comment: Have you tried `SemanticImport` instead?

Comment: Check `Import[file, "Table"]`, also `"Data"` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following data was created with Excel and saved as .txt

```
imp = Import["out.txt"]
```

[image]

```
ImportString @ imp // ListLinePlot
```

[image]

Or even shorter:

```
SemanticImport["out.txt"] // ListLinePlot
```